# Como criar um toolbar Duplo?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu pesquisei no google, mas eu nunca achei um modo de fazer um toolbar duplo(material design) como o da imagem:
https://chris.banes.me/content/images/2014/11/layout-structure-toolbars-toolbars-04_large_xhdpi.png

Em todo lugar que ja fui mostram apenas como fazer o toolbar simples. Se for mais facil , apenas me direcionem o que devo procurar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está utilizando o `Toolbar` então a maneira mais fácil de ter um `Extended Toolbar` é usando um valor de `layout_height` diferente do `?attr/actionBarSize` (que é o valor padrão).

Nessa [resposta do Chris Banes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491689/how-do-i-declare-an-extended-height-toolbar-action-bar-on-android-lollipop), ele recomenda usar um tamanho de `128dp` para ficar aderente ao spec do Material Design.

Seguindo a dica, você teria algo como:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Para chegar nesse layout completo, recomendo algo desse tipo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="128dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:minHeight="364dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É claro que precisa adaptar ao seu caso, mas o começo é por ai.

Comment: Obrigado @Wakim , ja foi metade do problema, o difícil é colocar a segunda toolbar(a branca) por cima.

Comment: Ah sim, posso colocar aqui uma dica, mas o mais fácil é montar via layout mesmo, um `FrameLayout` combinado com um `CardView` utilizando uma margem pra ficar abaixo do `Toolbar`.

Comment: opa, deu certo, obrigado.